# Group by Wrap up Code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a challenge with getting my data to group according the respective wrap up code.

I have a view that looks like screenshot A, my attempt results in screenshot B when in actual fact my results need to return Screenshot C.

In short I need to group the NULLS into the respective final outcome for that SegmentType Interact+hold+wrap make up one call

Apologies in advance for the post format.

**Screenshot A**

[image: vw_Conversations]

**Screenshot B**

[image: Query Result]

**Screenshot C**

[image: Desired Output]

Code Examaple

```
SELECT TOP 1000
  vw_Conversations.direction
 ,vw_Conversations.conversationId
 ,vw_Conversations.username
 ,vw_Conversations.conversationStart
 ,vw_Conversations.wrapUpCode
 ,DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, vw_Conversations.segmentStart, vw_Conversations.segmentEnd) AS Duration

FROM dbo.vw_Conversations

WHERE vw_Conversations.purpose = 'user'
OR vw_Conversations.purpose = 'agent'
AND vw_Conversations.segmentType <> 'alert'

  GROUP BY vw_Conversations.direction
        ,vw_Conversations.username
        ,vw_Conversations.wrapUpCode
        ,vw_Conversations.conversationStart
        ,DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, vw_Conversations.segmentStart, vw_Conversations.segmentEnd)
        ,vw_Conversations.conversationId
```

Comment: if you don't want to group by `wrapUpCode ` field why do you add in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: Maybe my post isnt that clear, I do want to group by WrapUpcode, each record has multiple segments which make up a call, the wrapupcode only appears on the wrapupcode segment which splits my call duration into 2... NULL and the Wrap up code. I require the total duration to be counting across all the segments and return the wrap up code, refer to screenshot 3